# Find the shortest distance between $9x^2+9y^2-30y+16=0$ and $y^2=x^3$

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Find the shortest distance between $9x^2+9y^2-30y+16=0$ and $y^2=x^3$.
I know the shortest distance exists between the curves on the common normal line. Is there any other shorter way to attempt?

Comment: Do you know the lagrange multiplier ?

Comment: No, but it'll help if that works.(I've just cleared high school, and they didn't teach it there)

Comment: Mh i guess you mean the distance between $M:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 9x^2 + 9y^2 - 30 y +16 =0 \}$ and $N:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y^2=x^3\}$

Comment: Yep(the shortest distance). Just tell me how to try a solution. I think I can work the rest.

Comment: The first curve is a circle. So all you have to do is minimize $(x-x_1)^2 +(y-y_1)^2$ if $(x_1,y_1)$ is the centre.

Comment: You solved it or need more help ?

Comment: Solved it-thanks! Should I put it up?

Comment: The actual shrtest distance is sqroot(13) /3

Answer (score 4):

As the first curve is a circle you only have to find its center, and than compute the normal equations of your second curve. the one which goes through the center of the circle will do the job. 
$$
\begin{align*}9x^2 + 9y^2 -30y+16 &= 9 \left( x^2+y^2 - \frac{10}{3}y +\frac{16}{9}\right)\\
&=9 \left(x^2+y^2-2\cdot \frac{5}{3} +\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2 -\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2 +\frac{16}{9}\right)\\
&=9\left(x^2 +\left( y- \frac{5}{3}\right)^2 -1\right)=0
\end{align*}$$
So the center of the circle wil be $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{5}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Do you mean $(0,5/3)$?

Comment: Yeah if you like this notation more

Comment: It's not a matter of my personal tastes: writing the coordinates of a point as a column vector is not standard notation. It could be a hindrance to someone trying to learn from this.

Comment: $ \dfrac{13}{9}$